# Entries with multiple categories, limit categories to just one parent and it's selected children?

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Not sure if this can be done natively or if an add-on is out there.

I'm trying to figure out a way to limit entries with multiple parent categories to just one parent and it's children. The reason, I have nested product URL's:

```
http://domain.com/products/parent_cat/child_cat/entry
http://domain.com/products/parent_cat/child_cat/grand_child/entry
```

Currently this works well for products with a single parent category.

Right now entries with multiple parent categories build "bad" URL's in the search results with this template code:

```
<a href="/products/{categories}{category_url_title}/{/categories}{url_title}">{title}</a>
```

Which works, if the entry has only one parent category assigned to it. If it has multiple, I get a nested URL with parent and child categories mixed together:

```
http://domain.com/products/parent_cat/other_parent/child_parent_cat/child_other_parent_cat/entry
```

Any ideas on how I could limit the parent & child categories to just one parent tree? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working correctly by using the [Primary Category](http://www.solspace.com/docs/primary_category) extension as Yuri recommended! I thought I would post my solution to help others in the future.

I created a conditional to check if the primary category is set and then built the URL based off the condition.

So if it returns true, the `{primary_category_url_title}` is placed outside the `{categories}` variable pair since it's going to be skipped inside the pair. Then I have another condition to skip all categories that don't have the same `parent_id` as the primary category set.

```
{if primary_category_id}
    <li><strong>{product_ci_model}</strong>: <a href="/products/{primary_category_url_title}/{categories}{if parent_id == primary_category_id}{category_url_title}/{/if}{/categories}{url_title}">{title}</a> - <em>Product<em></li>
{if:else}
    <li><strong>{product_ci_model}</strong>: <a href="/products/{categories}{category_url_title}/{/categories}{url_title}">{title}</a> - <em>Product<em></li>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Primary Category](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/primary-category) might help you

Comment: I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can us the limit function with `{categories}` pair tag. This would still allow multiple categories, parent and children, but only display one for url purposes. like

```
<a href="/products/{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}/{/categories}{url_title}">{title}</a>
```

Otherwise, take a look at GWCode's [GW Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories). It allows an insane amount of category control.

Comment: I've tried this. If I `limit=2` it will output the parent categories first, then the childs: `http://domain.com/products/parent_cat/other_parent_cat/entry`

Comment: I thought you said you were looking to get 1 category. The limit should be set to 1 not 2, otherwise, you're still dealing with multiple items. Not being related back. GW Categories will possibly give you better handling.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I only wanted to build the url from one parent tree. The `limit` parament loops through parents first, then children. I was able to do it with Primary Category and conditionals